# Alternate option field

Tags: bash, getopts

In a script i have a list of options that needs to be entered by the user.

They are

`-c cell name` -> it must be there

`-n node` -> it must be there

`-s server` -> it must be there

Uptill here its all fine my code until here looks like `while getopts c:n:s:`

The problem starts from here,

I have two other fields that needs to be entered in an and/or conditon.

`-i initial heap size`

`-m max heap size`

The user inputs either both these options or either one.

Currently i have something like

```
#get the arguments -c for cell, -n for node, -s for server, -i for initial heap, -m for max heap
while getopts c:n:s:im opt; do
        case $opt in
          c)
                CELL=$OPTARG
                ;;
          n)
                NODE=$OPTARG
                ;;
          s)
                SERV=$OPTARG
                ;;
          i)
                INI_HEAP=$OPTARG
                ;;
          m)
                MAX_HEAP=$OPTARG
                ;;
          ?)
                echo "a.sh -c <CELL> -n <NODE> -s <SERVER> [-i <INITAIL HEAP> | -m <MAX HEAP>"
                ;;
        esac
done

#test if cell name is not null
if ! test "$CELL" || ! test "$NODE" || ! test "$SERV" ; then
        echo "a.sh -c <CELL> -n <NODE> -s <SERVER> [-i <INITAIL HEAP> | -m <MAX HEAP>]"
        exit 1
fi

#test if both initial heap and max heap are null
flag=0
if ! test "$INI_HEAP" ; then
        if ! test "$MAX_HEAP" ; then
                flag=1;
        fi
fi

if [[ $flag -eq 1 ]] ; then
        echo "flag a.sh -c <CELL> -n <NODE> -s <SERVER> [-i <INITAIL HEAP> | -m <MAX HEAP>]"
        exit 1
fi

#test for non numeric value of initial heap size
if [[ "$INI_HEAP" == +([0-9]) ]] ; then
        continue
else
        echo "num a.sh -c <CELL> -n <NODE> -s <SERVER> [-i <INITAIL HEAP> | -m <MAX HEAP>]"
        exit 1
fi
```

How can i get to implement the and/or feature of `-i` and `-m` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$flag` variable is redundant - you set it, then immediately test for it. You could just echo instead of setting it originally. So the logic is:

- capture opts/optargs
- make sure that CELL, NODE and SERVER are all set
- make sure that either INI_HEAP or MAX_HEAP is set, and is an int

```bash
#get the arguments -c for cell, -n for node, -s for server, -i for initial heap, -m for max heap
while getopts c:n:s:i:m: opt; do
        case $opt in
          c)
                CELL=$OPTARG
                ;;
          n)
                NODE=$OPTARG
                ;;
          s)
                SERV=$OPTARG
                ;;
          i)
                INI_HEAP=$OPTARG
                ;;
          m)
                MAX_HEAP=$OPTARG
                ;;
          ?)
                echo "Usage: a.sh -c <CELL> -n <NODE> -s <SERVER> [-i <INITIAL HEAP> | -m <MAX HEAP>]"
                exit 1
                ;;
        esac
done

#test if cell name is not null
if [[ -z "$CELL" || -z "$NODE" || -z "$SERV" ]]; then
    echo "Cell, Node and Server are mandatory values"
    echo "Usage: a.sh -c <CELL> -n <NODE> -s <SERVER> [-i <INITIAL HEAP> | -m <MAX HEAP>]"
    exit 1
fi

#make sure either -i or -m was used (or both) and is an integer
shopt -s extglob
if [[ ( -z "$INI_HEAP" && -z "$MAX_HEAP" ) || -n "${INI_HEAP##+([0-9])}" || -n "${MAX_HEAP##+([0-9])}" ]]; then
    echo "Initial heap size or maximum heap size (or both) must be specified, and must be an integer"
    exit 1
fi
shopt -u extglob
```

Comment: currently i am not in my testing machine to try the code out. I will check on it and update you.. thanks for your effort. :)

Comment: could you please explain what does the code `shopt -s extglob` do. I am confused about that part.

Comment: That enables (and later disables) extended globbing, which allows this expression to work: `"${INI_HEAP##+([0-9])}"` - this is a parameter expansion which effectively means "remove all the digits from the beginning of `$INI_HEAP`. Then -n tests to see if there is anything left, and returns true if there is (ie $INT_HEAP was not an integer to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

I would add a default values for both INI_HEAP and MAX_HEAP before getopts case segment. The default could be a hard coded value, or some sort of smart value that first looks how much system has memory and gives a percentage value as default.